# ViewModel architecture dillema

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I have three fragments each with a RecyclerView of its own. If the user chooses a path from the first fragment, it takes him to the next fragment with relevant courses based on the selection, and then chooses a course and goes to the last fragment with relevant lessons. So each RecyclerView is dependant on data from the previous RecyclerView.

[image]

I used the shared ViewModel for all fragments but it didn't work well because they will all get initialized when the activity starts, because the data retrieval function is in the Repository which is initialized in the ViewModel.

I used a separate ViewModel for each one of them scoped to the activity, but didn't work well also because the data gets retrieved once only when the activity starts and never again, so when navigating between fragments back and forth the same data and items show up.

If i scope the individual ViewModels to the fragment only, then the latter fragment cannot access the data needed from the previous one.

How can this dilemma be solved using ViewModel Architecture? or should i just use SafeArgs to pass data?

**CourseViewModel**

```
class CourseViewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private val courseDataRepository = CourseRepository(app)
    val courseData = courseDataRepository.courseData
    val selectedCourse = MutableLiveData<Course>()
}
```

**CourseFragment.kt**

```
class CourseFragment : Fragment(),
    CourseRecyclerAdapter.CourseItemListener {

    private lateinit var viewModel: CourseViewModel
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course, container, false)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.courseRecyclerView)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host )

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CourseViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.courseData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val adapter =
                CourseRecyclerAdapter(
                    requireContext(),
                    it,
                    this
                )
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        } )
        return view
    }
```

This was my previous shared model before i abandoned it:

```
class SharedViewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private val pathDataRepository = PathRepository(app)
    val pathData = pathDataRepository.pathData
    val selectedPath = MutableLiveData<Path>()

    private val courseDataRepository = CourseRepository(app)
    val courseData = courseDataRepository.courseData
    val selectedCourse = MutableLiveData<Course>()

    private val lessonDataRepository = LessonRepository(app)
    val lessonData = lessonDataRepository.lessonData
    val selectedLesson = MutableLiveData<Lesson>()
}
```

Comment: A better approach would be to use separate viewmodels and just pass the id from fragment to fragment and fetch the necessary data either from the local database or the server. The answer by @ReazMurshed is nice and solves your sharing viewmodel problem but your actual problem is separation of concerns. Down the road your viewmodel will become a god viewmodel doing all sorts of things in loosely related screens like main, list and detail. The only thing common between main and list fragment is the id of the selected list. And the common thing between list and detail is the id of the course

Comment: @sonnet , i am currently using seperate view models. And correctly the only thing they share between them is the Id, but middle CourseFragments retrieves data and images from the server which i want to pass to the last Detail fragment

Comment: I could have the CourseFragment retrieve data and also have the Detail fragment then retrieve the same data, which is something i wanted to avoid

Comment: Store the data in a sqlite database using android room or sqldelight. And any decent image loading library will cache the images. Only the first time your images will be downloaded from the server and from next time on it will load the image from app's cache dir. You can also invalidate this image cache based on your requirements. Overall, this is a nicer approach. SharedViewModel between fragments scoped to a root/parent fragment has its usecases but this is not one of them imo.

Comment: @sonnet, the sqlite database idea sounds like a very decent approach, i definitely do think its the best possible approach, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @sonnet, I solved the issue by storing data in a Room database and then retrieving it whenever the user entered/re-entered any fragment and therefore limiting remote data retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can architect the fragments to have the following structure.

```
MainFragment
 - CourseFragment 
 - DetailsFragment
```

The idea is to make the `MainFragment` as a parent and launch the other two fragments using `getChildFragmentManager()` from the `MainFragment` as follows.

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, courseFragment)
    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Now create a `ViewModel` for `MainFragment` and scope that `ViewModel` to the life-cycle of your `MainFragment`. That will work as a shared `ViewModel` for both `CourseFragment` and `DetailsFragment`. You can access the `ViewModel` scoped to your parent fragment (i.e. `MainFragment`) as follows.

```
SharedViewModel vm = ViewModelProviders.of(getParentFragment())
                         .get(SharedViewModel.class);
```

Comment: Murshedm i already have a sharedviewmodelfor the MainFragment, my main problem is the other way around, i cannot share data from CourseFragment to DetailFragment

Comment: You can share the data between those using that shared viewmodel.

Comment: From your code, it looks like you are creating `ViewModel` for each of your fragments. I am not sure where you are creating a shared ViewModel.

Comment: The MainFragment ViewModel is shared among all fragments

Comment: I have edited the code for the previous shared view model that i had before but was not working correctly

Comment: But while accessing the `ViewModel` from the `CourseFragment`, you are scoping it to this specific fragment - you are not using the shared one I think. Use `viewModel = ViewModelProvider(getParentFragment()).get(CourseViewModel::class.java)`. In that case you also need to set the `MainFragment` as the parent of those two child fragments.

Comment: I got you, i will try that technique out thanx.

Comment: Definitely, let me know if you run into issues. Happy coding!

Comment: ViewModelProvider(getParentFragment()) doesn't work because it gives me a type mismatch.

Comment: It's expecting a ViewModelStoreOwner

Comment: How do i you make the MainFragment a parent of others?

Comment: I updated the answer with the fragment transaction. You need to do this from the `MainFragment`.